# Does mapbox setPaintProperty method process expressions?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Does mapbox setPaintProperty method process expressions?

```
map.setPaintProperty('places',
                'circle-radius',
                [
                    'interpolate',
                    ['linear'],
                    ['number', ["get", "Time", ['object', ["get", "Day", ['object', ["get", "Stats"]]]]]],
                    0, 4,
                    5, 24
                ]
            );
```

I get an error saying:

```
Error: layers.places.paint.circle-radius[2][1][1]: Expected string but found number instead.
```

I find the error confusing as I would think it should be returning a number.

I am somewhat certain the following expression works as I use it when implementing my addLayer()

```
paint: {
            'circle-radius': [
                'interpolate',
                ['linear'],
                ['number', ["get", "Time", ['object', ["get", "Day", ['object', ["get", "Stats"]]]]]],
                0, 4,
                5, 24
            ],'circle-opacity': 0.8
        }
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does mapbox setPaintProperty method process expressions?

Yes, I've used setPaintProperty with interpolate expressions without an issue.

Comment: I figured it out (thanks to you asking me to put it in fiddle) I wasn't casting my keys to strings and therefore was getting an error I was receiving.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey, maybe you should edit this so the answer is more clear now.